# Allocation of an array as part of an derived data type in conjunction with OpenMP

Tags: gcc, parallel-processing, openmp

In the following example, I allocate an array (as part of a derived data type) once inside a parallel block and once outside of it. As this array is used `private`, both ways should work according to OpenMP 3.0 specifications (I compiled with gcc-4.6.3)

In the present variant, `allocate` should be thread safe. But at runtime I get the error of reserving an already reserved variable.

```
module Example_mod
contains
  subroutine unter(n1,n2)
    implicit none
    type daten
       real, allocatable, dimension(:,:)::x
       integer::n1,n2
    end type daten
    integer, intent (in)::n1,n2
    integer l
    real,dimension(4)::ausgabe 
    type(daten)::xs

    ! initializing xs: 
    ! xs%n1 = n1
    ! xs%n2 = n2
    ! allocate(xs%x(n1,n2))  
    ! xs%x = 1.1

    !$omp parallel private(xs)
    xs%n1 = n1
    xs%n2 = n2
    allocate(xs%x(n1,n2))  
    xs%x = 1.1

    !$OMP DO
    do l = 1, 4
       xs%x = l**2
       ausgabe(l) = sum(xs%x)
    enddo
    !$omp end DO
    deallocate(xs%x)
    !$OMP end parallel
    ! deallocate(xs%x)
    write(*,*) ausgabe
  end subroutine unter
end module Example_mod

program main
  use Example_mod
  call unter(10,12)
end program main
```

In the other variant (uncommenting the 4 lines following `! initializing xs:` and commenting these lines within the `PARALLEL` block), the dimension and allocation status of the copies of `xs` to each thread should have been inherited from the original `xs`. But at runtime I get a segmentation fault, according to `gdb` upon entering the `PARALLEL` part.

I compiled with `gfortran -g -fopenmp <filename>`. Omitting `-fopenmp` reveals the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime, I've found a [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=38724#c5) about exactly this behaviour. It turns out that the Fortran2003 feature of allocatable components is not supported even by OpenMP 4.0.

> This OpenMP API specification refers to ISO/IEC 1539-1:2004 as Fortran 2003. The following features are not supported:
>
> • IEEE Arithmetic issues covered in Fortran 2003 Section 14
>
> • Allocatable enhancement

I hope this helps others.